# Render Settings for 32 Cores

Tags: rendering

I have an old server with an Intel Xeon CPU with 32 cores. What are the best render settings to use these many cores so that it renders fast?

Comment: Rendering scales linearly with number of cores. So render setting for X cores is the same as for 1 core.

Comment: I would change the tiles size to 8 x 8.

Comment: Fisrt: do not trust anyone's answers (not even mine)... **make your own tests**. Usually CPUs require smaller tile sizes than GPUs, start with 16x16 and start making the tiles larger until you find the optimal setting. Note that the reason there is no "correct" answer for this is because every system is different (Processor type, available RAM, other processes running simultaneously, etc will change the results... moreover, even on the same machine different scenes with different complexity might need different tile sizes. Test, test, test...